# Google Domain: Error 404 while redirecting to external site with cname www

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, hosting, cname

I have purchased a two domains from google. Let's say a.com and b.com

My Appengine project is linked to a.com

I just have to redirect from b.com to a.com

I have forwarded the naked domain to a.com and have pointed the CNAME 'www' to '@'

But still, http://b.com gets redirected but, http://www.b.com does not get redirected. Instead I get an Error 404

Additionally, I think, the above purchased domain do not have fixed ip, hence pointing A-record of b.com to IP of a.com seems not possible

Comment: How is it GWT-related? App Engine and DNS.

Answer (score 1):

After having a long conversation with the Google Apps Representative, it seems that the configuration is all fine, but if you purchase a domain for google and do not pay additionally for google apps for atleast one user, subdomain forwarding is not possible.

In my opinion, just allowing naked domain forwarding but blocking subdomain forwarding (for essential subdomain like www) is not completely helpful. Cname redirects or subdomain forwarding to external site should have been allowed, whether or not a customer pays for google apps.

To sum it up, it seems that for every domain you purchase from google you are compelled to purchase a registration of google apps.

Answer (score 0):

The Google App Engine service allows custom domains through virtual hosting. Adding a CNAME in DNS will fail because you need to configure a domain alias in order for App Engine to recognise it.

Add your domain alias through your corresponding Google Apps account as explained [here](http://thinkinghard.com/blog/HowToDoVirtualHostingOnGoogleAppEngine.html)

If your domain alias is not that important in itself, configure URL forwarding on the DNS level, this will redirect your browser to the primary domain.

Incidently, it's not because an IDE plug-in such as the Google Eclipse plug-in doesn't distinguish between GWT and App Engine projects that you shouldn't either: this is totally unrelated to GWT :-) (you linked this on the Google+ GWT community)